# How to change the default shortcuts for copy/paste in urxvt?

Tags: terminal, copy-paste, archlinux, xorg, rxvt

I'm trying to set up copy/paste actions using `ctrl+shift+c/p` like it is done in GNOME terminal but for urxvt. I didn't find any simple solution - it seems like it always requires scripts, hacks etc which gets me annoyed when it comes to such a basic things. That's why I'm wondering if it is possible to just change/add some entries in `~/.Xresource` to move the default behavior from `ctrl+alt+c/p` to `ctrl+shift+c/p` - since the former already works as expected.

Also, there is a lot of notions regarding clipboard itself: X calls them "selections" rather than "clipboards"; there are PRIMARY and CLIPBOARD selections; etc. I don't really understand all these subtleties - so feel free to be verbose!

I use Xorg server with i3 WM if it makes sense and `rxvt-unicode v9.22 - released: 2016-01-23`

Answer (score -3, accepted):

short: no, you can't

longer: I pointed out in *[Rebinding CTRL-ALT-[C|V] to CTRL-SHIFT-[C|V] in URxvt >= 9.20](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/294337/rebinding-ctrl-alt-cv-to-ctrl-shift-cv-in-urxvt-9-20/294552#294552)* that the binding for these is essentially hardcoded in urxvt without an easy way to change them (aside from external scripts or modifying the program itself).

Comment: Please, could you provide more details on how to apply this script and finally get urxvt using the new bindings?

Answer (score 31):

Contrary to Thomas' answer, it looks like you can. [In the same question he referenced](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/361540/27344) Spencer and Enno both mention that you can bind the native eval extensions in your `.Xresources` file. This would look like the following:

```
URxvt.keysym.Shift-Control-V: eval:paste_clipboard
URxvt.keysym.Shift-Control-C: eval:selection_to_clipboard
```

To disable the previous keybindings, you'll also need:

```
URxvt.keysym.Control-Meta-c: builtin-string:
URxvt.keysym.Control-Meta-v: builtin-string:
```

You can reload the file with:

```
xrdb -load .Xresources
```

You'll need to restart `rxvt` for the changes to take effect.

Comment: I recommend to put `URxvt.iso14755 : false` before it. It turns off this "yellow box" at the bottom.